# rocket vertical landing

Tags: gravity, aerodynamics, rocket-science, aircraft

SpaceX has published a couple of videos that show one of their heavy-lift rockets landing vertically in a highly specific location.

How is it possible that they are able to control so many variables as to make the such a large rocket's flight so perfectly predictable?

Is there some kind of new gyroscopic technology that I'm not aware of that makes possible such an incredible and unprecedented feat of aerospace engineering?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This is more of an engineering question rather than a physics question, so I've voted it be closed. You might consider resubmitting it on [Engineering Stack Exchange](//engineering.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Just balancing a tall object is not that hard. Try balancing a yardstick on your hand. Longer objects are easier. It is easier to balance a yardstick on your hand than a pencil.

Comment: Or better yet [Space Exploration](http://space.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Multi-variable model-predictive process control technology has been around for some time now (at least since the mid 1980's).  This means that the number of variables in the control problem is not an insurmountable problem.  Assuming that the SpaceX process control engineers have a good intuitive understanding of the theoretical aspects of landing their rocket (and this is a very good bet), they are left with the job of tuning their control scheme such that process feedback from the environment will allow the control system to adjust for the environmental variables that can't be predicted (e.g., wind gusts).

Comment: Right. Key is to respond quickly to external stimuli - but since the rocket is tall, you have time. It's a question of response time for the system that provides the restoring forces - not "new gyroscopes".

Comment: They launch this rocket up to low earth orbit and then have it land directly in the centre of a similar pad to the one it launched from.  It just seems rather unprecedented.     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grasshopper_(rocket)#/media/File:ORBCOMM-2_First-Stage_Landing_(23271687254).jpg                        This is the rocket directly before landing.  That's an amazing degree of precision for a fast moving object that's travelled a huge distance and up to LEO altitudes and back... Wowzers.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to think that they may have improved or re-engineered their gyroscopic technology in order to achieve faster response times.  The term 'gyroscopic technology' could very well include the software systems that make use of a gyroscope's readings.

Comment: Im just surprised that this amazing technological development hasn't made a bigger splash in the popular media in its own right.  You'd think that there might be some kind of market for simply delivering things extremely quickly to remote locations using similarly-equipped rockets.

Comment: @numbynumb , gyroscopic technology is going to be feedback control only.  I suspect that the SpaceX engineers have a control scheme that predicts the path of their rocket, and uses feedback control to correct for small deviations from the control scheme's predictions.

Comment: @numbynumb: Automatic control systems were very sophisticated in the 60s. The Apollo Lunar Module was programmed not only to land on the moon at a specific place, but to rendevous in orbit. [*Here's a good first-hand account.*](http://www.doneyles.com/LM/Tales.html) That's not to say it's a slam-dunk, as the SpaceX people are showing.

Comment: @MikeDunlavey Perhaps, but the lunar module was much lighter, shorter, and more compact.  And it was never able to successfully land on earth.